# how to convert string of year, in the format of yyyy/yyyy into a date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a dataframe with one column of dates such as 2002/2003, which means the year from 2002 to 2003. What would be the best way to convert this into a date so I can reflect this into a graph of years.

Comment: I would pick start of the year. 1st January 2002 for 2002/2003

Comment: When does 2002/2003 become 2003/2004 - if there's a specific date for the switchover - e.g. for the tax year boundary or similar, it might make more sense to use that start date as the reference.

Comment: preferably I would like just the year showing if that's not possible then I have a particular month I would use, this defaults to 01/01/2002. How would I change the month start to be like 01/08/2002.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from 2002 to 2003, year is 2002 (2002 up to 2003)

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'].str.split('/').str[0], format='%Y')
```

Since you are talking about a DataFrame I assume you are using Pandas.

**Update:**

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'].str.split('/').str[0].dt.year
```

or

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'].str.split('/').str[0].dt.strftime('%Y')
```

Comment: preferably I would like just the year showing if that's not possible then I have a particular month I would use, this defaults to 01/01/2002. How would I change the month start to be like 01/08/2002.

Comment: This is showing `2002` as `datetime` value.
It's splits `2002/2003` on `/` and `str[0]` gives you the first element, that is `2002`

Comment: Thank you the years work and are correct but the date fields now show as:

2003-01-01
2002-01-01

If possible I would like it just at 2002, 2003, if this is not possible then can I change it so the starting point is 01-08-2002 DDMMYYYY

Comment: Try this; `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'].str.split('/').str[0].dt.year` or `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'].str.split('/').str[0].dt.strftime('%Y') `
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: Thanks you got it!

Comment: Glad I could help you. I've updated my answer and would you please accept it.